# Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000) sqlite ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am getting this error "Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000) sqlite ios", when my sql query is large.
I am not using any wrapper for sql queries.
Please suggest

Comment: You might want to provide more information than just the error message.  Like maybe the query.

Comment: @iShameem, Same problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/43145117/632951