# Django, using "|": Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm trying to concatenate many querysets together. I tried out the marked answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431628/how-to-combine-2-or-more-querysets-in-a-django-view) question a while back, but that didn't work in my case. I needed to return a `queryset` not a list. So I used the `|`, from the second answer. This worked fine at the time, but now that I'm trying to use it again for something else I get the following error:

```
Expression tree is too large (maximum depth 1000)
```

I originally thought that `|` would concat the querysets, but after reading the docs it appears that it concats the actual query. And that this specific problem occurs if the query becomes too long/complex.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
def properties(self, request, pk=None):
    project = self.get_object()
    if project is None:
        return Response({'detail': 'Missing project id'}, status=404)

    functions = Function.objects.filter(project=project)
    properties = Property.objects.none()
    for function in functions:
        properties = properties | function.property_set.all()
    return Response([PropertySerializer(x).data for x in properties])
```

Since the `functions` query returns roughly 1200 results, and each `function` has about 5 properties, I can understand the query becoming too long/complex.

How can I prevent the query from becoming too complex? Or how can I execute multiple queries and concat them afterwards, while keeping the end result a queryset?

Comment: You query the wrong way I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to obtain all the `Property` objects that have as `Function` a certain project.

We can query this with:

```
properties = Property.objects.filter(function__project=project)
```

This thus is a queryset that contains all property objects for which the `function` (I assume this is a `ForeignKey`) has as `project` (probably again a `ForeignKey` is the given `project`). This will result in a single query as well, but you will avoid constructing gigantic unions.

Alternatively, you can do it in two steps, but this would actually make it slower:

```
# probably less efficient
function_ids = (Function.objects.filter(project=project)
                                .values_list('pk', flat=True))
properties = Properties.object(function_id__in=function_ids)
```